# value does not fall within expected range c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am developing a client application in c#. Created a tcp socket with Streamsocket. Able to connect with server and after retrieving configuration from server I get this exception in my application.
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within expected range.

```
StreamSocket tcpsocket = new StreamSocket();
tcpSocket.ConnectAsync(server, port, tls1.2);
..
DataReader dataReader = new                 Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(tcpsocket.InputStream);
dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
Task t = dataReader.LoadAsync(1024).AsTask();
t.Wait();
..
int attempt=0;
while (attempt++ < 4)
{   
if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0) {
byte[] buffer = new byte[dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength]
buffer = dataReader.ReadBytes();
...
}
```

and then passing on the buffer, i get configuration in 3 attempts 350 bytes, 25 bytes, 16 bytes and 4 bytes

Comment: remove the task and try it normally if it works. (just for testing)

Comment: are you sure you have 1024 bytes in your data reader ?

Comment: added more info. I check for unconsumedbufferlength and read it

Comment: which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: After receiving the last configuration item of 4 bytes.

Comment: can this be related to number of bytes? as if avoid that last 4 bytes I dont see the error. I'm confused by this behavior.

Comment: Anyone who can help on this ....